# How to group the records at ID level and only select associated counts based on whether columns are NULL or NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, databricks-sql

I have the below record set, which is created by joining two tables.

| A.ID | A.COMPANY_CODE | A.COUNTRY | B.CO_ID | B.CNTRY | COALESCE(B.CO_ID, B.CNTRY) | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | United States of America | null | United States of America | United States of America | 33 |
| 1 | 1234 | United States of America | 1234 | null | 1234 | 6 |
| 1 | 1234 | United States of America | 1234 | null | 1234 | 1 |
| 2 | 5678 | United States of America | null | United States of America | United States of America | 33 |

I want to group by ID and get the sum(CNT) for each ID. In case B.CO_ID is present, it should only select the associated CNT and ignore CNTRY for that ID. And when CO_ID is null, I want to sum based on Country. Below is the desired output -

| A.ID | SUM(CNT) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 33 |

I tried writing a case condition but it is not working. Any guidance would be super helpful. Please let me know if I need to provide any additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just need conditional aggregation and a `CASE` condition

```sql
SELECT
  t.ID,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(t.CO_ID) = 0
    THEN SUM(t.CNT)
    ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN t.CO_ID IS NOT NULL THEN t.CNT END)
  END AS CNT
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.ID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3150c1105cf07023630d0c63f451607c)

Note that `COUNT(SomeValue)` counts the number of non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

a `CASE WHEN` helps to select the correct correct numbers

The CTE even for the derived table, must be as TSQL doesn't like EXOSTS in grouping funct1ons

> ```
> CREATE TABLE derived_table (
>   
>   "ID"    INT,
>   "COMPANY_CODE" INT,
>   "COUNTRY" varchar(50),
>   "CO_ID" INT,
>   "CNTRY" varchar(50),
>   "CNTRY2" varchar(50),
>   "CNT" INT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO derived_table
>   ("ID",  "COMPANY_CODE" , "COUNTRY", "CO_ID",     "CNTRY", "CNTRY2",     "CNT")
> VALUES
>   (1,     1234,   'United States of America',     null ,  'United States of America' ,    'United States of America',     33),
>   (1,     1234,   'United States of America',     1234,   null,   '1234',     6),
>   (1,     1234,   'United States of America',     1234,   null ,  '1234',     1),
>   (2,     5678,   'United States of America',     null,   'United States of America',     'United States of America',     33);
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT ID
> , CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM derived_table WHERE CNTRY IS NULL AND "ID" = d1."ID") AND CNTRY IS NULL THEN CNT
> WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM derived_table WHERE CNTRY IS NULL AND "ID" = d1."ID") AND CNTRY IS NOT NULL THEN CNT
> ELSE 0 END cnt_
> FROM derived_table d1)
> SELECT ID, SUM(cnt_) FROM CTE GROUP BY ID
> ```

> ```
> ID | (No column name)
> -: | ---------------:
>  1 |                7
>  2 |               33
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=966f293ff8e1d4191d526aaee38b2d09)*